# Script shell how to decrease x minutes to a given date?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I need to decrease 10 minutes to a **given date :**

```
givenDate = 2017-11-07 19:20:37
```

**when executing :**

```
newDate=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' --date="$givenDate - 10 minutes")
echo $newDate
```

**I get :**

> 2017-11-08 06:21:37

**instead of**

> 2017-11-07 19:10:37

Please Help.
Thanks you.

Comment: Add your OS and date version to your question.

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
 date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' --date="-10 minutes $givendate"
```

Answer (score 3):

`date` is waiting for date in format "*Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800*", so your "*- 10 minutes*" appending is treated as timezone + 1 minute.

So, add your timezone to the reference date:

```
$ givenDate="2017-11-07 19:20:37 $(date +%:::z)"
```

Comment: Good catch. Also, the alternative is to say `"$givenDate 10 minutes ago"`.